# What should I pass in MyApp in main?

Tags: flutter, stream

Parameter is missing error occurred while using this code

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  final StreamChatClient client;

  MyApp(this.client);

}
```

Comment: Please explain your issue more clearly.

Comment: Because i put myapp  with this.client as argument it throws an error that a parameter is missing when I call myapp in main,I am building a chat application looking at this https://pub.dev/packages/stream_chat_flutter

Comment: Yes this will throw an error because you are expecting a parameter but haven't passed any argument.

Comment: Where is the materialapp?

Comment: here is the full code https://gist.github.com/brughwani/d3940a02a0fb9c322ab7a4aece23fb38

Comment: Have you checked my answer?

Comment: yes i did ,this is the error The argument type 'StreamChatClient?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'StreamChatClient'.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this will throw an error because you are expecting a `parameter` but haven't passed any `argument` in it. To solve this you can make your parameter `optional` and `StreamChatClient` `nullable` like below

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  final StreamChatClient? client;

  MyApp({this.client});

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be like this , because you are creating a constructor and it should be wrapped inside a curly  braces.
And the required part may be optional for the user to user.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
final StreamChatClient client;

MyApp({required this.client});


  ]
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
```

Comment: this was not helpful